# Что такое normalize.css?

Tags: html, css, html5

Добрый день изучаю верстку ,и  учитель прежде чем верстать всегда добавляет файл `normalize.css` и говорит это для нормирования .Кто может обьяснить что это за `"нормирование"`?ведь без этого файла тоже все работает прекрасно

Comment: http://rightblog.ru/2685

Comment: http://nicolasgallagher.com/about-normalize-css/

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Это некая альтернатива `reset.css`. У каждого браузера есть свои стандартные стили и чтобы обеспечить кроссбраузерность(то есть чтобы он выглядел одинаково во всех браузерах) нужно добавить этот волшебный файл. Это как начать жизнь с нового листа.

Comment: Нормалайз — это не ресет, не вводите в заблуждение людей. В данный момент ваш ответ неверен.

Comment: @Sasha Omelchenko перечитайте

Comment: @karaname это единый вормат всех тегов для кросс платформенности а ресет это обнуление с последующим преданием вида )у каждого своя ролб зря вы начали отталкиваться от ресета